# Accessing contents of a particular tag in a javascript string variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTTP post response object gotten by an AJAX post. I have it as a string. I want to access the contents of the first`<pre>` tag in the variable.

Example:

```
<html>
  <pre> First </pre>
  <pre> Second </pre>
</html>
```

I want to get the text "First". How can i do this? I used dojo xhrpost to perform ajax post.

Comment: Why is it tagged [[tag:ruby-on-rails]]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
var str = '<html><pre> First </pre> <pre> Second </pre> </html>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
alert(div.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.